# Matching two Observable Data Objects with combineLatest

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, combinelatest

I have two observable arrays: First array object observable

```
 array1= Observable.of({
      data: [
      {
          name: 'test',
          lastname: 'last'
        },
         {
          name: 'test1',
          lastname: 'last1'
        }
      ]
    }).map(res => {
      return res.data;
    });



// Second Observable:
    array2 = Observable.of('test1');
```

Expected Result from the above two array is that wherever firstname is matching with array2 value, get the lastname from that object.

```
//Expected Result: 
object3=Observable.of('last')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using RxJS 5.4 so you could do it like this for example:

```
Observable.combineLatest(array1, array2)
  .map(([users, name]) => {
    const user = users.find(u => u.name === name);
    return user ? user.lastname : null;
  })
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-4nyq3s?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks martin! Quick question- if array2 is a result of another combineLatest this would still work right

Comment: It doesn't matter. It just needs to emit at least one item in order to let emit `combineLatest` anything. In practise this is usually guaranteed by appending `startWith()`

Comment: Did not understand startWith() implementation

Comment: For example `array1.startWith(null)`